# How to make function not change pointer form argument once done?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void insert_node(Node *p){
    Node *tmp;
    tmp = new Node;
    tmp = p;
    if(first == NULL){
        status ++;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        first = tmp;
    }
    else{
        status ++;
        tmp->next = first;
        first = tmp;
    }
}


void Resize_content(){

    if( status2 >= 7*space/10){
        Entry *tmp;
        tmp = new Entry[2*space];
        for(int i=0;i<space;i++){
            Node *paux;
            paux = content[i].first;
            while(paux){
                //Node &caux = *paux;
                tmp[paux->hash_index%(2*space)].insert_node(paux);
                paux = paux ->next;
            }
        }
        delete[] content;
        content = new Entry[2*space];
        content = tmp;
        space = 2*space;
    }

}
```

`content` is a vector lists Entry of size space. Once the number of elements s above 70% of space  msut respace it moving the elements to different positions . the trouble is with elements form the same list because paux->next after  insert_node becomes NULL and are not moved

Comment: Your function doesn't make sense. First you create a `new Node`, storing its address in `tmp`. Then you leak it (losing the only pointer to it) by assigning `p` into `tmp`. Then you do some operations on `*p` (through pointer `tmp`). What are you *trying* to do?

Comment: i am trying to move Nodes from a list to another

Comment: There's too little information for us: what's `first` and `status`? Try to provide a [minimal, self-sufficient example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: first is the first Node of the list and status is used in future functions but it has no relevance here

Comment: It's being assigned into, so it *does* have relevance here. At least show how you call this function, saying what the state is before and what the expected & actual states are after.

Comment: in status i keep how many elements the list has

Comment: "i am trying to move Nodes from a list to another" Without changing the original list? Then you have to _copy_ the nodes.

Comment: it is not that somple because Node contains another list with pointers to another vector of entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, this should be the solution:

```
void insert_node(Node *p){
    if(first == NULL){
        status ++;
        //make p the start of a new 1-member list
        p->next = NULL;
        first = p;
    }
    else{
        status ++;
        // prepend p to existing list
        p->next = first;
        first = p;
    }
}


void Resize_content(){
    if( status2 >= 7*space/10){
        Entry *tmp;
        tmp = new Entry[2*space];
        for(int i=0;i<space;i++){
            Node *paux;
            paux = content[i].first;
            while(paux){
                Node *caux = paux;  //store current node's address
                paux = paux ->next;  // remember next node to process
                tmp[paux->hash_index%(2*space)].insert_node(caux);  //move current node
            }
        }
        delete[] content;
        content = tmp;
        space = 2*space;
    }

}
```

Is there a particular reason why you're doing this yourself instead of using `std::vector`, `std::list` (or `std::forward_list`) and/or `std::unordered_map` (for the entire hashing)?

Comment: Thank you man .  Now it works. It is an assigment for a course and i must make all the classes and function from scratch.

Comment: @AntonacheAlexandru Glad to have helped. It's generally a good idea to mention such limitations in the question. And pay attention to the question formatting preview before you actually submit it.